# Is it possible to join model types in Django into one object?

Tags: django, django-models

For example I have two model objects, Person and Address. Address has a reference to a Person id. What would a query look like that pulls them out together as one object, or is that not possible to do with Django?

Comment: This question is too vague. Provide more details.

Comment: The answer below and the comment provide all the needed details. His sample code is exactly what I have, but his solution doesn't suffice, because I need the reverse direction.

Comment: Editing your question to provide more clarity (complete with examples) will get you better answers, instead of people having to guess what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of the [Django docs on related objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects). Going from a Person to related Addresses is equivalent to going from a Blog to its related Entries in the examples.

If you have a person, you can do `person.address_set.all()` to get all addresses for that person.

If each person **has only one** address, use a [`OneToOneField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), and then you can use `person.address` to get the address.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to ask, but I'll give it a shot.

I'm gonna assume that your models look something like:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

class Address(models.Model)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    street = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
```

Now, get an address:

```
address = Address.objects.get(id=address_id)
```

Then you can reference the person like so:

```
address.person.first_name
```

Comment: Right, but my problem is that I don't know the address, I know the person. So I need to find the address for the person, or preferably be able to refer to the address off of a person.

Comment: In that case you can do something like.


address = Address.objects.all().filter(person=person)

Or, if you just have the person id, something like:


address = Address.objects.all().filter(person__id=person_id)