# Storing additional info about users in Django

Tags: django, django-models

For some reasons (particularly, to try making DB scheme upgrading easier), I need to store all the user's extended properties in another object (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323522/is-it-possible-to-join-model-types-in-django-into-one-object) to separate Person and Address)

I have an AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE override set and do capture `def_user_profile`.

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CustomUser.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The question is: if I add a custom type property to CustomUser, like this:

```
class CustomPropertySet(models.Model):
    this_is_a_Farmer = models.BooleanField()

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    extdata = models.CustomProperySet()
```

Will this automatically create a CustomProperySet entry at adding new user? Does CustomPropertySet needs to be associated back with ForeignKey to its CustomUser owner?
Second question: how to delete extended properties like this when object is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer to these is "try it and find out", but we're a polite people here...

- Will it automatically create CustomPropertySet?

When you assign something to `extdata` what do you assign? Assigning True and False probably won't work, you'd have to assign a CustomPropertySet instance, and to get one you'll have to create one.

Try it and this will become clear.

- Does CustomPropertySet need to point back to a CustomUser instance?

No. The CustomProper **t** ySet can survive all on it's lonesome. Your CustomUser points to it, but it's not bashful and doesn't care who or how many people point at it.

- How do delete cascading dependancies?

[See the documentation about cascading deletes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a model as a field of another model. It just doesn't work that way. Apart from anything else, there's a whole load of metaclass magic going on to turn model-level field declarations into instance-level attributes, and that simply won't work with a model like you have tried with `CustomProperySet`.

I can't really understand what you are trying to do, anyway. If you want extra data in your profile class, just add it - if you want the structure of that data shared with other classes, maybe subclassing would help.